# How to prevent NetBeans from remembering open files?

Tags: netbeans

When I start NetBeans, I don't want it to automatically open the files that were open when I last closed it.

The only way I found to do that is to delete the following files:

```
del /q "%APPDATA%\Netbeans\7.2.1\config\Windows2Local\Components\MultiView-java*"
```

Is there a better way, e.g. an option that prevents NetBeans from saving the state of the open files on exit?

Answer (score 5):

I know the question is very old but the issue is still there :) and the solution is the following:

Set/Open the desired starting files, project and then go to menu **`Window > Reset Windows`**.

It will remember whatever you had. So if you close all documents and call window reset, you will have no default opened files, which might be great for some of us.